# Append data from a fetch call to an API to my state

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this function below, that runs a function inside a forEach loop, like this:

```
async populateSystemData(id) {
    const response = await fetch('https://localhost:44389/api/systemlist/GetSystems/' + id);
    const data = await response.json();
    const result = Object.values(data);
    result.forEach((s) => {
        this.populatePlanetData(s.systemId);
    });
    this.setState({ systems: result, loading: false });
}
```

Here is the function that is executed inside the loop:

```
async populatePlanetData(id) {
    const response = await fetch('https://localhost:44389/api/planetlist/GetPlanets/' + id);
    const data = await response.json();
    const result = Object.values(data);
    this.setState({ planets: result, loading: false });
}
```

Here is how I'm writing this data out so the user can see it:

```
{systems.map(s =>
    <tr>
        <td>{s.SystemName}</td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Planets</td>
                </tr>
                {planets.map(p =>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{p.PlanetName}</td>
                    </tr>
                )}                                      
            </table>
       </td>
    </tr>
 )}
```

What's the best way to update the state inside the populatePlanetData so that it appends rather than overwrites?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Another approach to better leverage React components

based on the authors comment

```
there could be 200+ systems, with each system having 1 and up to 50 planets
```

Instead of cycling through functions and having one global state for loading, consider splitting into components.

Conceptually we need three components

- Systems - Load all systems and display all systems
- System - Load all planets from system and display planets
- Planet - Display content of planet

Let's go ahead and implement them

1. Systems

```js
function Systems({ id }) {
  const [systems, setSystems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getSystems = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://localhost:44389/api/systemlist/GetSystems/${id}`,
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      setSystems(Object.values(data));
    };
    getSystems();
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <table>
      {systems.map((system) => (
        <System system={system} />
      ))}
    </table>
  );
}
```

2. System

```js
function System({ system: { id, SystemName } }) {
  const [planets, setPlanets] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getPlanets = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://localhost:44389/api/systemlist/GetSystems/${id}`,
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      setPlanets(Object.values(data));
      setIsLoading(false);
    };
    getPlanets();
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <tr>
      {isLoading && <td>Loading...</td>}
      {!isLoading && (
        <>
          <td>{SystemName}</td>
          <td>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>Planets</td>
              </tr>
              {planets.map((planet) => (
                <Planet planet={planet} />
              ))}
            </table>
          </td>
        </>
      )}
    </tr>
  );
}
```

3. Planet

```js
const Planet = ({ planet: { PlanetName } }) => (
  <tr>
    <td>{PlanetName}</td>
  </tr>
);
```

What do you think about this approach?

Comment: Hi, this looks more readable. But I'm concerned that this wouldn't translate well to how I display this code to the user.  I've added additional code to my question that shows how I'm planning to write this to the website so the user can see the data.

Comment: I don't see how this should be an issue, I will update this answer.

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell I have updated my answer. How about this?

Comment: Hi, would these functions be inside my main React Component class or would they be separate code files?  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write all that code!  I created a "helper" js file and put these 3 functions inside there.  However, I'm kind of confused as to how to get this into my React Component.  Do I import the 'Systems' function and just place it in my component render method like <Systems /> ? thanks!

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell Sure. You're welcome! The Systems function is just another component and can be used within your render function or any other component with `<Systems id="123" />`, whereas id is used for your api call. Consider marking the answer as solving :)

Answer (score 2):

```
async populateSystemData(id) {
    const response = await fetch(`https://localhost:44389/api/systemlist/GetSystems/${id}`);
    const data = await response.json();
    const systems = Object.values(data);

    this.setState({ systems, loading: false });

    // good way to get async list data
    const planetsData = await Promise.all(systems.map(async (system) => {
      const res = await fetch(`https://localhost:44389/api/planetlist/GetPlanets/${system.systemId}`);
      const planetData = await res.json();

      return planetData;
    }));
    const planets = planetsData.map(planet => Object.values(planet));

    this.setState({ planets, loading: false });
}
```

Comment: You are missing an await in front of Promise.all :)

Comment: Also as Julian mentioned spread operator is a good way to update immutable state without overwrite

Comment: I also like your approach better with not updating the state so often.

Comment: You could return `res.json()` straight without await

Comment: @zemil does the spread operator go inside the map method?  thanks

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell I get your point. You should then use `reduce` function with an initial value of `[]`

Comment: @zemil It's almost a design question, if the single async method takes a while and will update something meaningful on the screen, updating the state in each iteration would be the better approach. If all requests are fast and not so many after all, then this approach is better.

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell, you can use the spread operator when you get new planetData inside map or another loop

Comment: @Julian, yeah I totally agree with you and I commended about your answer but If we have 100 systems we also have 100 rerenders)

Comment: @zemil I updated my answer, with your example but a reduce instead of a map function. What do you think?

Comment: @zemil there could be 200+ systems, with each system having 1 and up to 50 planets

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell so Promise.all and one this.setState after it is better for perfomance)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by spreading the oldState values

```js
this.setState(({ planets }) => ({ planets: [...planets, ...result], loading: false }));
```

As a little note - You should not set the loading in `populatePlanetData`. Rather use a map instead of a forEach and put a `await Promise.all(result.map(...))` around it, after you waited for all async operations you can go and set the loading state false.

UPDATE with changes from discussion in answer from @zemil

```js
async populateSystemData(id) {
  const api = `https://localhost:44389/api`;
  const response = await fetch(`${api}/systemlist/GetSystems/${id}`);
  const data = await response.json();
  const systems = Object.values(data);

  this.setState({ systems, loading: false });

  // good way to get async list data
  const planetsData = await Promise.all(
    systems.reduce(async (allSystemsPromise, system) => {
      const allSystems = await allSystemsPromise;
      const res = await fetch(
        `${api}/planetlist/GetPlanets/${system.systemId}`,
      );
      const planetData = await res.json();

      return [...allSystems, ...system];
    }, Promise.resolve([])),
  );
  const planets = planetsData.map((planet) => Object.values(planet));

  this.setState({ planets, loading: false });
}
```

Comment: about reduce I think for beginners it looks more difficult than another loops)

Comment: I agree, I also had to double check about promises, and you have to use `Promise.resolve([])` as initialValue. :D Still a cool approach

Comment: What is the purpose of this line, Promise.resolve([]))? Also I thought the first argument when calling reduce had to be a function, but you have allSystemsPromise, which I don't see defined anywhere.   thanks!

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell The allSystemsPromise is the first argument of the async function (which is the first argument to the reduce function). The `Promise.resolve([])` is the second argument of the reduce function and is the initial value